# How to run macro specific to multiple files in a folder?

Tags: vba

I have hashed together pieces of code to pull out a row of data from all worksheets in a folder based on a date (this part is manually entered via message box) then insert a new tab named summary into each workbook and then paste the row of data into it. I am able to do this in part but it is only working when I insert the macro into each workbook, but I need the code to be generic and loop through all closed workbooks in a folder.  I have put below my very badly written code which has a lot of duplication but don't know how to cleanse this without mucking it up and cannot make it work for closed workbooks, any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

This is the code:

```
Sub SheetnamesCopyRowToSummaryTab() 'Includes All Worksheets LATEST
Set WSNew = Worksheets.Add
WSNew.Name = "Site Name"
WSNew.Move Before:=Sheets(1)
Columns(1).Insert
For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
    Cells(i, 1) = Sheets(i).Name
Next i
     ActiveSheet.Name = "Summary"
     'WSNew.Range("B1:J1").Value = Array("Month", "Period", "Actual Consumption",     "Invoice Consumption", "Consumption Variance", "Simulated Cost", "Invoice Cost", "Cost Variance", "Cumulative Cost Variance")

Dim NumSheets As Long
NumSheets = Sheets.Count
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("Summary").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
On Error GoTo 0

Set WSNew = Worksheets.Add
WSNew.Name = "Summary"
WSNew.Move Before:=Sheets(1)
Dim strSeek As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For i = 1 To NumSheets
Range("A" & i) = Sheets(i).Name
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
strSeek = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter the invoice period that you wish to search for.", _
    Title:="Select Invoice Period", Default:="MARCH 2013")
    For Each WS1 In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    With WS1
        .UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=strSeek

        On Error Resume Next
        .AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row, .Columns.Count) _
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=WSNew.Range("A" & WSNew.Cells(WSNew.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Offset(1) 'Added .offset (1) this then took row from each ws but left blank rows on summary where there was no data on ws for the month
        On Error GoTo 0

        .AutoFilterMode = False
        'headers were placed here
    End With
Next WS1

Columns(1).Insert
For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
    Cells(i, 1) = Sheets(i).Name
Next i
ActiveSheet.Name = "Summary"
WSNew.Range("A1:J1").Value = Array("Site Name", "Month", "Period", "Actual Consumption", "Invoice Consumption", "Consumption Variance", "Simulated Cost", "Invoice Cost", "Cost Variance", "Cumulative Cost Variance")
Columns.AutoFit
Cells.Font.Size = 8
Range("B2:J12").Font.Bold = False
Range("A1:J1").Font.Bold = True
Range("A1:J1").Interior.Color = RGB(191, 191, 191)
Range("A1").RowHeight = 20
Range("A1:J1").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
Range("A1:J1").VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code works it's ok. I think there is some potential to clean it up, but that's hard without knowing what has to be done.

Your macro is always working on the ActiveWorkbook and ActiveSheet. So it could work, if you just open every Excel file in the folder, call your macro and close the (just opened) workbook.

Something like this: (it's just written down without thinking about performance or anything)

```
Public Sub LoopingThroughExcelFiles()
Dim fso As Object, wb As Workbook
Dim o As Object, pathToFolder As String
pathToFolder = "N:\" ' <-- has to be changed
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    For Each o In fso.GetFolder(pathToFolder).Files
        If InStr(o.Type, "Excel") Then
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(o.Path)
            SheetnamesCopyRowToSummaryTab
            wb.Close
        End If
    Next
Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

You can try it. Perhaps it works, but in any case you can see how to get the paths of every excel file in the given folder.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I tried your code it opened up the first file and went so far but fell down on the line with: .UsedRange in:                                                     For Each WS1 In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    With WS1
        .UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=strSeek - not sure why this is?  Thanks

Comment: Ok, so we have to change your macro a little bit. Just to test: if you set `strSeek="MARCH 2013"` and comment out the input box, does the error occur? (and what is the error message?)

Comment: It still stops at .UsedRange with the error message saying "Run time error 1004.  Method 'Open' of object 'Workbooks'failed".  It does open up first workbook, inserts summary tab and copies tab names into column A,then stops when trying to copy row of data, is there anyway I can attach sample files to this post?  Thanks

Comment: Ok. I've just seen another thing, that could cause the error. So please replace every "ThisWorkbook" with "ActiveWorkbook" in your code. (explanation: ThisWorkbook is the Workbook with the macro, ActiveWorkbook is the workbook you can see)

Comment: Glad to hear that. :) Now that it works you can inspect your code and try out if you can optimize it to your needs. For example i think the first few lines are unnecessary. (P.S. would be nice if you accept my answer, would be my first ;) )

Comment: Yes will look at tidying it up, and will accept your answer, my first post so was unsure of the protocol.  Thanks again you've been a great help.